# per target cuda compiler options with cmake

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

So I have a bit of an issue with setting up pdbs in cuda when using cmake and visual studio (2013 in the case).

Basically I think I want to do something like :

```
-Xcompiler "/Fd whatever.pdb"
```

to each `add_cuda_library`, but I can only seem to set `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS, CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE, CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG` etc globally.

Right now I use

```
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}; -Xcompiler "/Fd nvcc_all.pdb")
```

And this dumps all the symbols into one file.

Problem is sometimes the build breaks when there are concurrent writes to that pdb. I've tried adding /FS, but it doesn't help.

Is there a cmake incantation to allow me to add a per lib cuda pdbs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass the flags like this:

```
CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(foo
    ...
    OPTIONS "/Fd foo.pdb"
)
```